# Condição E OU no Pandas

Tags: pandas

Estou com uma dúvida para configurar os filtros `"e"` e `"ou"` no pandas.

Exemplo: Uma coluna que tenha os seguinte valores col1(sim, nao, talvez)

para buscar o sim OK

```
df[df['col1']=='sim']
```

Agora, para pegar:

sim ou nao

sim e nao

sim e Sim

Como faria?

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar o operador `|` para definir a operação OU, ou o operador `&` para a operação E.

```
df[df['col1'] == 'sim' | df['col1'] == 'nao']  # Retorna se for "sim" ou "nao"
df[df['col1'] == 'sim' & df['col1'] == 'nao']  # Retorna se for "sim" e "nao" (nunca)
```

No OU, você pode simplificar utilizando o método `isin`:

```
df[df['col1'].isin(['sim', 'nao'])]  # Retorna se for "sim" ou "nao"
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira mais intuitiva de fazer isso é utilizando o comando query, mas em questão de performance não é tão rápido quanto um 'isin' do pandas:

Sim ou Não

```py
df.query("col1 == 'sim' or col1 == 'nao'")
```

Sim e Não / este nunca acontece

```py
df.query("col1 == 'sim' and col1 == 'nao'")
```

Sim ou Sim / ambíguo

```py
df.query("col1 == 'sim' and col1 == 'sim'")
```